# $f''(e^{x})$ and it's definition

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, definition

I'm working through "The Calculus Tutoring Book" by Carol and Robert Ash (0-7803-1044-6).  In chapter 3.3, when discussing derivatives of basic functions, they show and define the $D_{x}e^{x}$ and subsequently define $e$.  Page 67 for those that have the book.

In any event, they define a "base", eventually, they land at $(1)$: $$D_{x}b^x = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} b^x\lbrack \frac{b^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x} \rbrack$$  I have no problem here.  And I understand why they effectively ignore the constant $b^x$ when you factor it out $(2)$:
$$\frac{b^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}$$ to $(3)$
$$D_{x}b^x=mb^x$$

And go on to state that the latter must be the slope of a line centered at $(0, 1)$

Then from the former, they land on the fact the $(4)$ $$D_{x}e^x = e^x$$

I don't see the path from $(2)$ to $(3)$ and subsequently $(4)$.

Comment: That is a very confusing notation I have never seen before. Usually you would write $(e^x)’$

Comment: I agree notation is odd. You're question is about the following: $\lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{b^{\Delta x}-1}{\Delta x}
=\ln(b)$?

Comment: no, my question is I don't understand how they landed on the fact that the derivative of $e$ = $e$ following the formulas outlined in the book.

Answer (score 1):

What they are doing, which is fairly sloppy the way it is phrased and justified, is the following.

- They assume that limits as $\Delta x\to0$ of expressions of the form $(2)$ exist, and that they are numbers $m(b)$ (depending on $b$)
- They argue "by picture" that, as $b$ moves between $1$ and $100$, the numbers $m(b)$ range from close to zero to very big
- They assume that $m(b)$ depends continually on $b$
- They assume that a continuous function satisfies the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)
- They put together all the above to conclude that there exists a number $e$ such that $m(e)=1$.
- It follows, by $(1)$, that $(e^x)'=e^x$.

*Comment: the notation you are using for derivatives is highly unusual, and it will be confusing for   anybody who sees is. One often writes $f'(x)$ for the derivative of the function $f$ at the point $x$. When you write $f'(e^x)$, what we all read is "the derivative of the function $f$, evaluated at the point $e^x$", which is not what you meant.*

Comment: Sorry, that is actually how it's presented in the book.  I copied it from there.  For obvious reasons, I cannot post a picture, but that's where it's from.

Comment: That's weird, because I'm looking at the book right now, and in both cases where you wrote $f'(b^x)$ it says $D_xb^x$, and where you wrote $f'(e^x)$ it says $D_xe^x$. Which is still not the most common notation,but at least it would be understood by most readers. Now, if you are reading whatever edition or something and it has that notation, that in itself would be huge red flag regarding that text.

Comment: You're correct, mea culpa.  I assumed, from the earlier sections on derivatives, that $D_{x}e^{x}$ == $f'(e^{x})$. I've updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the book but what they are doing in general is showing that $\frac{d}{dx} \ b^x = ln(b)\cdot b^x\cdot 1$ ..........where the $1$ is the derivative of the exponent x (chain rule)

This is a general rule so for example $\frac{d}{dx}\ 5^{3x}= ln(5)\cdot 5^{3x}\cdot 3$

When applying this rule to $e^x$ we get $\frac{d}{dx} \ e^x = ln(e)\cdot e^x\cdot 1 = e^x$